# Importing into R: XML data with repeating nodes

Tags: r, xml

Teaching myself R and getting the hang of it but can't wrap my head around importing XML data into a data frame. I keep getting errors from the tuts I'm following and believe it has to do with the fact that there are multiple child nodes with the same name. Any help with properly getting the below data into a df would be greatly appreciated.

This is the portion where I think the problem is occurring. There are multiple labels within each instance.

```
<instance>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <start>2.32</start>
      <end>22.32</end>
      <code>Rachel</code>
      <label> ### don't think label is necessary ###
        <group>Team</group> ### this should be the column name ###
        <text>Team A</text> ### this is the data ###
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group> ### this should be the column name ###
        <text>Passes accurate</text> ### this is the data ###
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>1st half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>52.4</pos_x>
      <pos_y>33.7</pos_y>
    </instance>
```

I expect it to look like this...

```
ID  START   END     CODE    TEAM    ACTION          Half        POS_X   POS_Y
1   2.32    22.32   Rachel  Team A  Passes accurate 1st Half    52.4    33.7
```

Here is a sample of the original XML. I only need the data contained in ALL_INSTANCES. Thanks for your help!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<file>
  <SORT_INFO>
    <sort_type>sort order</sort_type>
  </SORT_INFO>
  <ALL_INSTANCES>
    <instance>
      <ID>1</ID>
      <start>2.32</start>
      <end>22.32</end>
      <code>Rachel Sparrow</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>Team A</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Passes accurate</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>1st half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>52.4</pos_x>
      <pos_y>33.7</pos_y>
    </instance>
    <instance>
      <ID>2</ID>
      <start>2.32</start>
      <end>22.32</end>
      <code>Rachel Sparrow</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>Team A</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Positional attacks</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>1st half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>52.4</pos_x>
      <pos_y>33.7</pos_y>
    </instance>
    <instance>
      <ID>3</ID>
      <start>3.02</start>
      <end>23.02</end>
      <code>Taylor Heard</code>
      <label>
        <group>Team</group>
        <text>Team B</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Action</group>
        <text>Tackle</text>
      </label>
      <label>
        <group>Half</group>
        <text>1st half</text>
      </label>
      <pos_x>52.0</pos_x>
      <pos_y>32.4</pos_y>
    </instance>
  <ROWS>
    <row>
      <code>Start</code>
      <R>0</R>
      <G>0</G>
      <B>0</B>
    </row>
    <row>
      <code>Rachel Sparrow</code>
      <sort_order>1</sort_order>
      <R>51400</R>
      <G>51400</G>
      <B>51400</B>
    </row>
    <row>
      <code>Taylor Heard</code>
      <sort_order>2</sort_order>
      <R>51400</R>
      <G>51400</G>
      <B>51400</B>
    </row>
  </ROWS>
</file>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a full day of researching and testing I finally cobbled together a solution that works. I was able to get all the nested/repeated data from "text" node via:

```
nested_data <- xml_text(xml_nodes(myxml,"text"))
```

Because there was always 3 "text" fields in the same order I was able to grab every third entry via:

```
team <- nested_data[seq(1,length(nested_data),3)]
action <- nested_data[seq(2,length(nested_data),3)]
half <- nested_data[seq(3,length(nested_data),3)]
```

Full code for those that are in a similar boat...

```
library(rvest)
myxml <- read_xml("test_001.xml")
player <- xml_text(xml_nodes(myxml,"code")) #these don't repeat so are easy to grab and use
id <- xml_text(xml_nodes(myxml,"ID"))
time <- xml_text(xml_nodes(myxml,"start"))
nested_data <- xml_text(xml_nodes(myxml,"text")) #"text" is the actual data I want
team <- nested_data[seq(1,length(nested_data),3)] #grab every 3rd entry, starting at 1 position
action <- nested_data[seq(2,length(nested_data),3)] #grab every 3rd entry, starting at 2 position
half <- nested_data[seq(3,length(nested_data),3)] #grab every 3rd entry, starting at 3 position
pos_x <- xml_text(xml_nodes(myxml,"pos_x"))
pos_y <- xml_text(xml_nodes(myxml,"pos_y"))
df <- data.frame(id,time, half, team, player, action, pos_x, pos_y ) #final dataframe
```